# Decode UTF-8 URL in Perl

Tags: perl, decode, encode

Consider:

```
use URI::Escape;
print uri_unescape("%C3%B3");
```

Output : Ã³

Decode with this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Output : ó

This is the expected one.

What Perl library should I use to get the correct output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know that the byte sequence is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), then use `Encode::decode`:

```
use Encode;
use URI::Escape;

my $in = "%C3%B3";
my $text = Encode::decode('utf8', uri_unescape($in));

print length($text);    # Should print 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i am having hard time to grasp, what is a byte sequence ? and why need to apply that decode function ? i meant why uri_unescape not enough ?

Comment: @William The URI contains escaped *bytes*: `0xC3` and `0xB3`. Bytes have no meaning until you assign a meaning to them. If each byte contains one character, you get these weird characters. If these two bytes combined symbolize *one* character, you get your `ó`. The `URI::Escape` module has no idea what meaning to assign to these bytes. This is the task of you, the programmer, or a well-defined protocoll (compare the ASCII headers in HTTP requests that contain the `Content-encoding` metadata). All Unicode encodings have to be *multi-byte encodings*, because there is a vast pool of characters.

Comment: And that's why I prefaced my answer with "If you know that the byte sequence is utf-8, ..." It is also possible those bytes are part of a utf-16 stream in which case you need to decode with 'utf-16' instead of 'utf-8'. To be sure you need to ask the person who created those bytes how they should be interpeted.

Answer (score 1):

The code `Encode::decode('utf8', uri_unescape($in))` doesn't work for me, but the following code works well.

```
sub smartdecode {
    use URI::Escape qw( uri_unescape );
    use utf8;
    my $x = my $y = uri_unescape($_[0]);
    return $x if utf8::decode($x);
    return $y;
}
```

This code is from http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch05_02.htm

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

To summarize the problem —

- Input: `"%C3%B3"`
- Expected Output: `ó`
- Actual Output: `Ã³`

#### So, What Are These Data Formats?

Okay, so, let's analyze —

- `"%C3%B3"` : This *is not UTF-8 encoding* per-se.  This is URI/URL-encoding, i.e., like when a space is swapped with `%20`, so, you may have seen URL's like `example.com?file=That%20Thing%20I%20Sent%20You`.
- `ó`: This is what we want to decode.  With URL encoding, it is encoded as `%C3%B3`.  Feel free to check by inputting it here: https://www.urlencoder.org/ ; or check its spec here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm
- `Ã³`: What is this corruption?  `Ã` is the [UTF-8 character at `x00C3`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/index.htm) and `³` is the [UTF-8 character at `x00B3`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b3/index.htm).  (Source: In the links.)

#### URI-Encoding - TLDR

Just unescape your string with `uri_unescape`...

```
use URI::Escape;

my $string = "%C3%B3";
print(uri_unescape($string));
```

**[Full Working Demo](https://ideone.com/YY1RXr)**

#### No, you don't need a Package to use UTF-8 in Perl.  Even in Perl5.

As you can tell from above, the problem is not from UTF-8 encodings, but from URI encodings.

To display a UTF-8 string, simply `"\N{U+1234}"`, with 1234 being our hex char.

```
print ("\N{U+263A}");    # print a smiley face
```

**[Full Working Demo Online](https://ideone.com/yt9bbN)**

#### Handling Latin1 Extension Edgecases

You'll notice that `chr(243)` (which is ó) normally gives `�`, which is also what `"\N{U+00F3}` also gives.  What's the deal?  Proof: [IDEOne Demo](https://ideone.com/m5hlId)  This is explained in a note in the Perl Docs:

> Note that characters from 128 to 255 (inclusive) are by default internally not encoded as UTF-8 for backward compatibility reasons.

How to fix?  Easy: just indicate that your code uses UTF-8, like so...

```
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );

print ("\N{U+00F3}");
```

**[Full Working Demo](https://ideone.com/3MKo7m)**