# Javascript decode =C3=B3 quoted printable

Tags: javascript, encoding, quoted-printable

I have search a lot but cant find the solution, i want to decode a word like

> Documentaci=C3=B3n => Documentación

in javascript, but i cant.

I tried to convert to utf8 when word is like

> Documentaci%C3%B3n

and i can, but never with

> that "=" instead of "%".

I take that text from an email if that helps.

Thanks in advance if you can help me, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace that '=' with '%':

```
var str = "Documentaci=C3=B3n";
str = str.replace(/={1}/g, '%');
str = decodeURI(str);
```

It worked for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/5bkpw5kw/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/5bkpw5kw/1/)

**UPD1**: This is 'quoted-printable' encoding, as can be learned from [raw](https://marc.info/?l=olpc-argentina&m=131707228310718&q=raw) letter. I googled and tried deal of functions, here some of them

- [http://phpjs.org/functions/quoted_printable_decode/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160428185628/http://phpjs.org/functions/quoted_printable_decode/)
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/quoted-printable/blob/master/src/quoted-printable.js
- https://code.google.com/p/obremsdk/source/browse/trunk/js/quoted-printable.js?r=56

.. and [others](https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Fn4TVInpC-yk8weVsYCwDw&gws_rd=ssl#q=javascript%20decode%20quoted%20printable)

I also has taken code snippet from https://mothereff.in/quoted-printable (un[beautified](https://beautifier.io/) script is embeded into [html](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmothereff.in%2Fquoted-printable&charset=(detect%20automatically)&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices#source)):

```
var j = String.fromCharCode;
var a = function(l) {
    return l.replace(/[\t\x20]$/gm, "").replace(/=?(?:\r\n?|\n)/g, "").replace(/=([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/g, function(n, m) {
        var o = parseInt(m, 16);
        return j(o)
    })
};
```

All of them return me **DocumentaciÃ³n** , but sinse said snippet works fine on [mothereff.in](https://mothereff.in/quoted-printable) I assume all of them are valid. That must be some UTF-8 issue that I haven't still fixed. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163937/decode-utf-8-url-in-perl) or [google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%C3%83%C2%B3%20decode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=IIATVO2SM4ve8gfWsIGwDQ)

Updated fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/5bkpw5kw/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/5bkpw5kw/2/)

**UPD2**: working example by author [http://jsfiddle.net/fyoc1bvk/2](https://jsfiddle.net/fyoc1bvk/2/)

Comment: Yes, but cant do that in whole text, maybe there are correct "=", and to use decodeURI must be a string without spaces

Comment: Can you describe the situation - why it is urlencoded ? if this is part of url - there is no any = (%3D instead) nor spaces (+ or %20 instead). May be there is another error on the back-end or elswhere.

Comment: Hi iVenGO and thanks for the help, the text is from an email, if u use gmail and see the "original message" at the options, u can see there is this type of codification.

i have search in google an email like that and u can see an example here: http://marc.info/?l=olpc-argentina&m=131707228310718

there is the codification at the subject

Comment: May be use RexExp 'lookahead' lookaround like so:

(?=[A-Z0-9]{2})

Comment: I can do it with regex, but that was my last option, i think must be a better solution maybe. like utf8_decode or something like that, but nothing works

Comment: 2 hours spent for your issue: 'asked 2 hours ago' :)

Comment: Really really thank you, finally that works.

A working example is just here: http://jsfiddle.net/fyoc1bvk/

really thank you

Comment: welcome. append '(quoted-printable)' to your question if possible, for better searchablity

Comment: are you from Argentina?

Comment: No, im from Spain, the email was an example i found on Internet