# How does this URL encoding work?

Tags: perl, encoding, uri

I am trying to create an HTTP post request to a server. Part of the post parameters is a German movie title such as

```
 Cowboys & Aliens
```

or

```
 Das süße Leben
```

When the request gets posted by my browser the get posted as

```
 Cowboys+%26+Aliens
```

and

```
 Das+s%FC%DFe+Leben
```

I can't figure what type of encoding this is, and how to reproduce it in perl.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: It's called [URL encoding](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), and you can use [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Encode) module. That took me a whole 10 seconds of googling, next time try that first.

Comment: @Biffen, sorry if I haven't made that clear but I've been using URI::Escape, and googled before - that's basic etiquette. I started from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163937/decode-utf-8-url-in-perl but struggled to find a way that will encode/decode both strings consistently

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question. So what is your current problem, then?

Comment: This is just a guess, but could there be an issue with how the second string is encoded within your Perl file? The character ß is encoded as 0xDF in ISO 88591-1 but as 0xC3 0x9F in UTF-8. Perhaps could the issue be that the bytes are escaped ie. to %C3%9F rather than the UTF-8 code-point being mapped back to ISO 8859-1 and represented as %DF?

Comment: The CPAN documentation Biffen linked to discusses that reserved characters e.g. '&' are only encoded if you explicitly ask them to be - is this a potential issue you need to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Use [URI::Encode](http://search.cpan.org/~mithun/URI-Encode-v1.0.1/lib/URI/Encode.pm) this will do the job for you.